# Closest and Farthest points to the origin

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

I'm sorry to bother people with this but I simply do not fully understand about Quadratic forms as I don't think my book explains the more difficult parts of the process well enough which is I assume the same for most people that struggle with things.

$$ 11x_1^2 + 11x_2^2 + 14x_3^2 - 2x_1x_2 - 8x_1x_3 - 8x_2x_3 = 1
$$

Assuming I calculated the eigenvalues correctly I got 6, 12 and 18.
The corresponding eigenvectors to be (1,1,1), (-1,1,0) and (1,1,-2) resp.

Now we need to find the closest and farthest points to the origin, now I understand that the points closest to the origin corresponds to the eigenvalue 18 and the farthest to eigenvalue 6, what I don't understand is how to find them, I know I should put like $$\lambda_1 = 0$$ and $$\lambda_2 = 0 $$ and solve for the remaining one to figure it out but how exactly do I do that? A step by step just for this part would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try a simple case such as a rotated ellipse in 2-D. Can you find a geometric meaning for the eigenvectors?

Comment: Sorry about that, just a minor flaw in my text, it has been edited now.

Comment: @amd, you mean the formula you get for an ellipse? Other than that I just need to know what i asked for, learning the different surfaces and so on is something I'll just learn while I do exercises

Comment: Work through some simple examples with two-dimensional conic sections to see how the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the quadratic form relate to the geometry of the curves. It’s much easier to draw and visualize these things in two dimensions, and then you can generalize from there. For instance, what is the eigensystem for an ellipse in standard position? What happens to the eigensystem when you rotate the ellipse? Try the same thing with a hyperbola. And so on.